# A command line general sudoku solver in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, sudoku

I have this command line program that asks the user to (partially) input the source sudoku with some missing values, and after that validates the input and solves it.

See what I have:

**SudokuSolver.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.sudoku;

import java.awt.Point;
import java.util.Objects;

/**
 * This class implements a backtracking algorithm for solving square sudokus.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Feb 25, 2016)
 */
public class SudokuSolver {

    private static final int MINIMUM_DIMENSION = 1;
    private static final int UNUSED = 0;

    private final int dimension;
    private final int minisquareDimension;
    private Sudoku input;
    private final IntSet[] rowSetArray;
    private final IntSet[] columnSetArray;
    private final IntSet[][] minisquareSetMatrix;
    private final Point point = new Point();
    private Sudoku solution;

    public SudokuSolver(int dimension) {
        this.minisquareDimension = checkDimension(dimension);
        this.dimension = dimension;

        rowSetArray    = new IntSet[dimension];
        columnSetArray = new IntSet[dimension];

        minisquareSetMatrix = new IntSet[minisquareDimension]
                                        [minisquareDimension];

        for (int i = 0; i < dimension; ++i) {
            rowSetArray   [i] = new IntSet(dimension + 1);
            columnSetArray[i] = new IntSet(dimension + 1);
        }

        for (int y = 0; y < minisquareDimension; ++y) {
            for (int x = 0; x < minisquareDimension; ++x) {
                minisquareSetMatrix[y][x] = new IntSet(dimension + 1);
            }
        }
    }

    public Sudoku solve(Sudoku input) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(input, "The input sudoku is null.");
        this.input = new Sudoku(input);
        fixInputSudoku();
        clearSets();
        tryInitializeSets();
        solution = new Sudoku(dimension);
        solve();
        return solution;
    }

    // Checks that the requested dimension d = k^2 for some positive integer 
    // k, which means that we can form "miniquares". For example, if the 
    // dimension is 9, the dimension of a minisquare is 3.
    private int checkDimension(int dimension) {
        if (dimension < MINIMUM_DIMENSION) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "The requested sudoku dimension (" + dimension +
                    ") is too small. Must be at least " + MINIMUM_DIMENSION + 
                    ".");
        }

        int i = 1;

        while (i * i < dimension) {
            ++i;
        }

        if (i * i > dimension) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "The requested sudoku dimension (" + dimension + 
                    ") is not a square of a positive integer.");
        }

        return i;
    }

    private void fixInputSudoku() {
        int dimension = input.getDimension();

        for (int y = 0; y < dimension; ++y) {
            for (int x = 0; x < dimension; ++x) {
                int currentValue = input.get(x, y);

                if (currentValue < 1 || currentValue > dimension) {
                    input.set(x, y, UNUSED);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void clearSets() {
        for (int i = 0; i < dimension; ++i) {
            rowSetArray   [i].clear();
            columnSetArray[i].clear();
        }

        for (int y = 0; y < minisquareDimension; ++y) {
            for (int x = 0; x < minisquareDimension; ++x) {
                minisquareSetMatrix[y][x].clear();
            }
        }
    }

    private void tryInitializeSets() {
        for (int y = 0; y < dimension; ++y) {
            for (int x = 0; x < dimension; ++x) {
                int currentValue = input.get(x, y);

                if (rowSetArray[y].contains(currentValue)) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                        "The cell (x = " + x + ", y = " + y + ") with " +
                        "value " + currentValue + 
                        " is a duplicate in its row.");
                }

                if (columnSetArray[x].contains(currentValue)) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                        "The cell (x = " + x + ", y = " + y + ") with " +
                        "value " + currentValue + 
                        " is a duplicate in its column.");
                }

                loadMinisquareCoordinates(x, y);

                if (minisquareSetMatrix[point.y][point.x].contains(currentValue)) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                        "The cell (x = " + x + ", y = " + y + ") with " +
                        "value " + currentValue + 
                        " is a duplicate in its minisquare.");
                }

                if (isValidCellValue(currentValue)) {
                    rowSetArray   [y].add(currentValue);
                    columnSetArray[x].add(currentValue);
                    // This call saves the result in the field 'point'.
                    minisquareSetMatrix[point.y][point.x].add(currentValue);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean isValidCellValue(int value) {
        return 0 < value && value <= dimension;
    }

    private void loadMinisquareCoordinates(int x, int y) {
        point.x = x / minisquareDimension;
        point.y = y / minisquareDimension;
    }

    private void solve() {
        solve(0, 0);
    }

    private boolean solve(int x, int y) {
        if (x == dimension) {
            // "Carriage return": we are done with row 'y', so move to the row
            // 'y + 1' and set 'x' to zero.
            x = 0;
            ++y;
        }

        if (y == dimension) {
            // We have found a solution, signal success by return 'true'.
            return true;
        }

        if (input.get(x, y) != UNUSED) {
            // Just load a predefined value from the input matrix to solution,
            // and proceed further.
            solution.set(x, y, input.get(x, y));
            return solve(x + 1, y);
        } 

            // Find least number fitting in the current cell (x, y).
        for (int i = 1; i <= dimension; ++i) {
            if (!columnSetArray[x].contains(i)
                    && !rowSetArray[y].contains(i)) {
                loadMinisquareCoordinates(x, y);

                if (!minisquareSetMatrix[point.y][point.x].contains(i)) {
                    solution.set(x, y, i);
                    rowSetArray   [y].add(i);
                    columnSetArray[x].add(i);
                    minisquareSetMatrix[point.y][point.x].add(i);

                    if (solve(x + 1, y)) {
                        // A solution found; stop backtracking by returning
                        // at each recursion level.
                        return true;
                    }

                    // Setting 'i' at current cell (x, y) did not lead towards
                    // solution; remove from the sets and try larger value 
                    // for 'i' in the next iteration.
                    rowSetArray   [y].remove(i);
                    columnSetArray[x].remove(i);

                    // Reload the minisquare coordinates as they are likely to
                    // be invalid due to recursion.
                    loadMinisquareCoordinates(x, y);
                    minisquareSetMatrix[point.y][point.x].remove(i);
                }
            }
        }

        // No number fits at this (x, y), backtrack a little.
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Sudoku.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.sudoku;

/**
 * This class represents a sudoku matrix. It may be of any dimension and may 
 * contain arbitrary values at each cells.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Feb 25, 2016)
 */
public class Sudoku {

    public static final int MINIMUM_DIMENSION = 1;
    private final int[][] matrix;

    public Sudoku(int dimension) {
        checkDimension(dimension);
        this.matrix = new int[dimension][dimension];
    }

    public Sudoku(Sudoku sudoku) {
        this(sudoku.matrix.length);

        for (int y = 0; y < sudoku.matrix.length; ++y) {
            this.matrix[y] = sudoku.matrix[y].clone();
        }
    }

    public int get(int x, int y) {
        return matrix[y][x];
    }

    public void set(int x, int y, int value) {
        matrix[y][x] = value;
    }

    public int getDimension() {
        return matrix.length;
    }

    public boolean isValid() {
        int dimension = getDimension();
        int minisquareDimension = getMinisquareDimension();
        IntSet[] rowSetArray    = new IntSet[dimension];
        IntSet[] columnSetArray = new IntSet[dimension];
        IntSet[][] minisquareSetMatrix = new IntSet[minisquareDimension]
                                                   [minisquareDimension];

        for (int i = 0; i < dimension; ++i) {
            rowSetArray[i]    = new IntSet(dimension + 1);
            columnSetArray[i] = new IntSet(dimension + 1);
        }

        for (int squareY = 0; squareY < minisquareDimension; ++squareY) {
            for (int squareX = 0; squareX < minisquareDimension; ++squareX) {
                minisquareSetMatrix[squareY]
                                   [squareX] = new IntSet(dimension + 1);
            }
        }

        for (int y = 0; y < dimension; ++y) {
            for (int x = 0; x < dimension; ++x) {
                int currentValue = get(x, y);

                if (rowSetArray[y].contains(currentValue)
                        || columnSetArray[x].contains(currentValue)) {
                    return false;
                }

                int squareX = x / minisquareDimension;
                int squareY = y / minisquareDimension;

                if (minisquareSetMatrix[squareY]
                                       [squareX].contains(currentValue)) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String maximumCellValueString = "" + matrix.length;
        int fieldLength = maximumCellValueString.length();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (int y = 0; y < matrix.length; ++y) {
            sb.append(rowToString(y, fieldLength));
            sb.append('\n');
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }

    private String rowToString(int y, int fieldLength) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (int x = 0; x < matrix.length; ++x) {
            sb.append(String.format("%" + fieldLength + "d", get(x, y)));

            if (x < matrix.length - 1) {
                sb.append(' ');
            }
        }

        return sb.toString();
    } 

    private void checkDimension(int dimension) {
        if (dimension < MINIMUM_DIMENSION) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "The input dimension is too low: " + dimension + 
                    ", should be at least " + MINIMUM_DIMENSION + ".");
        } 
    }

    private int getMinisquareDimension() {
        int i = 1;
        int dimension = getDimension();

        while (i * i < dimension) {
            ++i;
        }

        if (i * i > dimension) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "Impossible to form minisquares: " +
                    "the dimension of this sudoku (" + dimension + ") is not " +
                    "a square of a positive integer");
        }

        return i;
    }
}
```

**IntSet.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.sudoku;

/**
 * This class implements a trivial integer set used for keeping track which 
 * cell values are allowed at each sudoku cell.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Feb 25, 2016)
 */
final class IntSet {

    private final boolean[] table;

    IntSet(int sudokuDimension) {
        this.table = new boolean[sudokuDimension];
    }

    void add(int number) {
        table[number] = true;
    }

    boolean contains(int number) {
        return table[number];
    }

    void remove(int number) {
        table[number] = false;
    }

    void clear() {
        for (int i = 0; i < table.length; ++i) {
            table[i] = false;
        }
    }
}
```

**App.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.sudoku;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * This class implements a command line utility for solving sudokus.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Feb 25, 2016)
 */
public class App {

    /**
     * Default dimension of the input sudoku.
     */
    private static final int DEFAULT_DIMENSION = 9;

    private final int dimension;
    private Sudoku inputSudoku;
    private SudokuSolver solver;

    public App(int dimension) {
        this.dimension = dimension;

        try {
            this.inputSudoku = new Sudoku(dimension);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            System.err.println("ERROR: " + ex.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    private void createSolver() {
        this.solver = new SudokuSolver(dimension);
    }

    private void scanDigits() {
        int cellsToScan = dimension * dimension;
        int y = 0;
        int x = 0;

        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            while (cellsToScan > 0) {
                if (!scanner.hasNextInt()) {
                    break;
                }

                int cellValue = scanner.nextInt();
                inputSudoku.set(x++, y, cellValue);

                if (x == dimension) {
                    x = 0;
                    ++y;
                }

                --cellsToScan;
            }
        }
    }

    private void solve() {
        System.out.println("[Input sudoku]");
        System.out.println(inputSudoku);

        try {
            long startTime = System.nanoTime();
            Sudoku solution = solver.solve(inputSudoku);
            long endTime = System.nanoTime();

            if (!solution.isValid()) {
                throw new IllegalStateException(
                        "ERROR: The computed solution is not valid.");
            }

            System.out.println("[Solution]");
            System.out.println(solution);
            System.out.printf("Solution took %.2f milliseconds.\n", 
                              (endTime - startTime) / 1e6);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.err.println("ERROR: " + ex.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int requestedDimension = getDimension(args);
        App app = new App(requestedDimension);

        try {
            app.createSolver();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            System.err.println("ERROR: " + ex.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }

        app.scanDigits();
        app.solve();
    }

    private static int getDimension(String[] args) {
        int dimension = DEFAULT_DIMENSION;

        if (args.length > 0) {
            try {
                dimension = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                System.err.println(
                        "ERROR: \"" + args[0] + "\" is not an integer.");
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }

        return dimension;
    }
}
```

**Usage guidance**

In order to solve your sudokus, you could start the program and input the matrix at the command line. A better approach is to save your source sudoku into a file `sudoku.txt`:

```
1 0 0 0 0 7 0 9 0
0 3 0 0 2 0 0 0 8
0 0 9 6 0 0 5 0 0
0 0 5 3 0 0 9 0 0
0 1 0 0 8 0 0 0 2
6 0 0 0 0 4 0 0 0
3 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
0 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 7
0 0 7 0 0 0 3 0 0
```

and type `cat sudoku.txt | java -jar YOUR.jar 9` (It can handle any square sudoku of dimension \$n\$ if \$n = m^2\$, where \$m\$ is a positive integer; \$n = 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, ....\$.)

**Critique request**

Please, tell me anything that comes to mind.

Comment: Many of your methods could (and should) be declared static (e.g. checkDimension). And the int i = 1; should be a constant instead of 1 (it is the square root of MINIMUM_DIMENSION as far as I can see, so probably MINIMUM_DIMENSION should be declared in terms of this new constant instead)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Use java functions instead of reinventing the wheel

> ```
>     int i = 1;
>     while (i * i < dimension) {
>         ++i;
>     }
> ```

There is a java function for this, `Math.sqrt()` when using a while loop like that people need to realize its just a home made implementation of the mentioned function.

```
int i = (int)math.sqrt(dimension);
```

### Don't shut the program done on invalid input

> ```
>         try {
>             dimension = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
>         } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
>             System.err.println(
>                     "ERROR: \"" + args[0] + "\" is not an integer.");
>             System.exit(1);
>         }
> ```

Provided you wanted to reuse this piece of code in an environment where java solves multiple sudoku's in parallel, if at least 1 input file is invalid, then the whole java process will be killed. Instead, throw the exception back to the caller, so it can deal with it, using a custom (checked) exception even makes it more clear that the caller can expect that some input files are invalid.

### Again, dont reinvent the wheel

> ```
> final class IntSet {
> ```

You define your own class for keeping boolean constants, java already has this class since version 1.6, its called [BitSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html)

- Instead of `void add(int number) {`, you have [`void set(int bitIndex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#set(int))
- Instead of `boolean contains(int number) {` you have [`get(int bitIndex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#get(int))
- Instead of `void remove(int number) {` you have [`clear(int bitIndex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#clear(int))
- You don't need to change `clear()`

Answer (score 1):

**Choose better names for functions**

`private int checkDimension(int dimension)` - this function does not "check dimension". It returns the size of minisquares! So name it `calculateMiniSquareDimension(int largeSquareDimension)`. Maybe shortcut `Dim` for `Dimension` will be OK.

**Avoid class envy**

function `void fixInputSudoku()` works on fields of `input` object (by using `get` and `set`). It is better to move this function to class `Sudoku` therefore.